# Ruby multiple joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

Here are the models I created in my Rails app:

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shelter
  belongs_to :type
end

class Shelter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
end

class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
end
```

I'm trying to find shelters that don't have any exotic pets in them but am stuck joining the tables in the way where I can retrieve that information! Here is my latest attempt where I believe I'm at least reaching the Types table. Any help and explanation on joins would be much appreciated!

```
Shelter.joins(:pet => :type).where(:types => {exotic => false})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is impossible to get the results you want using just JOINS. Instead you need to find which shelters *do* have exotic pets and then negate that.

One way to accomplish that is through a subquery:

```
Shelter.where(<<~SQL)
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM pets 
    INNER JOIN types ON types.id = pets.type_id 
    WHERE shelters.id = pets.shelter_id 
      AND types.exotic IS TRUE
  )
SQL
```

Of course that involves a lot of explicit SQL, something I don't mind, but others do not like it.

You can also do something similar using just the ActiveRecord query interface.

```
shelters_with_exotics = Shelter.joins(pets: :type).where(types: { exotic: true })
Shelter.where.not(id: shelters_with_exotics)
```

NOTE: The queries for the two examples are different. If it mattered you would need to benchmark both of them to determine which one performed best.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to query. Noted that you have to negate - thank you for such a thorough answer!!